# how to search "n bits" in a byte array?

Tags: c++, c

i have a byte array. Now i need to know the count of appearances of a bit pattern which length is N.

For example, my byte array is "00100100 10010010" and the pattern is "001". here N=3, and the count is 5.

Dealing with bits is always my weak side.

Comment: Do you count overlapping matches?

Comment: just to understand what you mean:
"00010010 01001001" is count here again 5?

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: Why do you need to ask that?

Comment: how many bytes do you have in your byte array?

Comment: @Viktor isn't it a bit unusual?

Comment: @Viktor Because there may be a better solution than matching bit patterns.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth:it's abstracted from some ACM exercises i work on and some other cases in encoding staff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could always XOR the first N bits and if you get 0 as a result you have a match. Then shift the searched bit "stream" one bit to the left and repeat. That is assuming you want to get matches if those sub-patterns overlap. Otherwise you should shift by pattern length on match.

Comment: You still need to take care at the byte boundaries but yes, basically this is the right approach.

Comment: Inefficient for longer inputs, but it works. (Consider the case where the pattern is 100 bits - you don't need to XOR all of them after you've found the first 1 bit)

Comment: Of course you don't have to do that. I was trying just to give a basic algorithm. I think its much better than giving a full blown optimized code, because it then leads to plain copy-paste which obviously isn't what we want :)

Answer (score 1):

If N may be arbitrary large You can store the bit pattern in a vector

```
vector<unsigned char> pattern;
```

The size of the vector should be

```
(N + 7) / 8
```

Store the pattern shifted to the right. By this, I mean, that for example, if N == 19, Your vector should look like:

```
|<-    v[0]   ->|<-    v[1]   ->|<-    v[2]   ->|
 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
|         |<-             pattern             ->|
```

If You have Your pattern originally shifted to the left, You can use the function I'll present below, to shift the bits to the right.

Define a vector of bytes, of the same length as the pattern, to store a part of Your bit stream for comparing it with the pattern. I'll call it `window`

```
vector<unsigned char> window;
```

If N is not an integer multiple of 8, You will need to mask some leftmost bits in Your `window`, when comparing it with the pattern. You can define the mask this way:

```
unsigned char mask = (1 << (N % 8)) - 1;
```

Now, assuming the `window` contains the bits, it should, You could theoretically compare the pattern with the `window` using vector's operator == like this

```
window[0] &= mask;
bool isMatch = (window == pattern);
```

But there are good reasons to be a little bit more sophisticated. If N is large and Your byte array, You look for the pattern in, is significantly larger, it's worth it, to process the pattern and build a vector of size N+1:

```
vector<int> shifts;
```

This vector will store the information, how many bits to shift the bit stream by, for the next comparison, based on the position, at which there is a mismatch in the current `window`.

Consider the pattern `0001001100`. You should compare the bits with the `window` from right to left. If there is a missmatch at the first bit, You know it's 1 and the first occurrence of 1 in Your pattern is at the position 2 counting form 0 form the right to the left. So in that case, You know, that it doesn't make sense to make a comparison if the number of new bits shifted form the bit stream into the `window` is less than 2. Similarly if the mismatch occurs at the third bit (position 2 counting form 0), the `window` should be moved by 7, because 3 consecutive zeros in your pattern are at the end. If the mismatch is at the position 4, You can move the `window` by 8 and so on. The `sifts` vector, at an index `i` will hold number of bits, by which to move the `window`, if the mismatch occurs at the position `i`. If there is a match, the `window` should be moved by the number of bits stored in `shifts[N]`. In the example above, a match means a shift by 8.

In practice of course, You compare whole bytes form the pattern with the bytes from the `window` (going form right to left) and if there is a mismatch You examine the bits in the byte to find the mismatch position.

```
if(window[i] != pattern[i])
{
    int j = 0;
    unsigned char mismatches = window[i] ^ pattern[i];
    while((mismatches & 1) == 0)
    {
        mismatches >>= 1;
        ++j;
    }
    mismatch_position = 8 * (window.size() - i - 1) + j;
}
```

Here is a function that might come handy, when You need to shift some bits from Your bit stream into the `window`. I wrote it in C#, but conversion to C++ should be trivial. C# makes some casts necessary, that are probably not necessary in C++. Use `unsigned char` instead of `byte`, `vector<unsigned char> &` instead of `byte []`, `size()` instead of `Length` and maybe some more minor tweaks. The function is probably a little more general than needed in Your scenario, as it doesn't use the fact, that consecutive calls retrieve consecutive chunks of Your byte array, which maybe could make it a bit simpler, but I don't think it hurts. In the current form, it can retrieve arbitrary bit substring form the byte array.

```
public static void shiftBitsIntoWindow_MSbFirst(byte[] window, byte[] source,
                                                int startBitPosition, int numberOfBits)
{
    int nob = numberOfBits / 8;
    // number of full bytes from the source

    int ntsh = numberOfBits % 8;
    // number of bits, by which to shift the left part of the window,
    // in the case, when numberOfBits is not an integer multiple of 8

    int nfstbb = (8 - startBitPosition % 8);
    // number Of bits from the start to the first byte boundary
    // The value is from the range [1, 8], which comes handy,
    // when checking if the substring of ntsh first bits
    // crosses the byte boundary in the source, by evaluating
    // the expression ntsh <= nfstbb.

    int nfbbte = (startBitPosition + numberOfBits) % 8;
    // number of bits from the last byte boundary to the end

    int sbtci;
    // index of the first byte in the source, from which to start
    // copying nob bytes from the source
    // The way in which the (sbtci) index is calculated depends on,
    // whether nob < window.Length

    if(nob < window.Length)// part of the window will be replaced
    // with bits from the source, but some part will remain in the
    // window, only moved to the beginning and possibly shifted
    {
        sbtci = (startBitPosition + ntsh) / 8;

        //Loop below moves bits form the end of the window to the front
        //making room for new bits that will come form the source

        // In the corner case, when the number by which to shift (ntsh)
        // is zero the expression (window[i + nob + 1] >> (8 - ntsh)) is
        // zero and the loop just moves whole bytes
        for(int i = 0; i < window.Length - nob - 1; ++i)
        {
            window[i] = (byte)((window[i + nob] << ntsh)
                | (window[i + nob + 1] >> (8 - ntsh)));
        }

        // At this point, the left part of the window contains all the
        // bytes that could be constructed solely from the bytes
        // contained in the right part of the window. Next byte in the
        // window may contain bits from up to 3 different bytes. One byte
        // form the right edge of the window and one or two bytes form
        // the source. If the substring of ntsh first bits crosses the
        // byte boundary in the source it's two.

        int si = startBitPosition / 8; // index of the byte in the source
        // where the bit stream starts

        byte byteSecondPart; // Temporary variable to store the bits,
        // that come from the source, to combine them later with the bits
        // form the right edge of the window

        int mask = (1 << ntsh) - 1;
        // the mask of the form 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
        //                         |<-  ntsh ->|

        if(ntsh <= nfstbb)// the substring of ntsh first bits
        // doesn't cross the byte boundary in the source
        {
            byteSecondPart = (byte)((source[si] >> (nfstbb - ntsh)) & mask);
        }
        else// the substring of ntsh first bits crosses the byte boundary
        // in the source
        {
            byteSecondPart = (byte)(((source[si] << (ntsh - nfstbb))
                                   | (source[si + 1] >> (8 - ntsh + nfstbb))) & mask);
        }

        // The bits that go into one byte, but come form two sources
        // -the right edge of the window and the source, are combined below
        window[window.Length - nob - 1] = (byte)((window[window.Length - 1] << ntsh)
                                                | byteSecondPart);

        // At this point nob whole bytes in the window need to be filled
        // with remaining bits form the source. It's done by a common loop
        // for both cases (nob < window.Length) and (nob >= window.Length)

    }
    else// !(nob < window.Length) - all bits of the window will be replaced
    // with the bits from the source. In this case, only the appropriate
    // variables are set and the copying is done by the loop common for both
    // cases
    {
        sbtci = (startBitPosition + numberOfBits) / 8 - window.Length;
        nob = window.Length;
    }


    if(nfbbte > 0)// The bit substring coppied into one byte in the
    // window crosses byte boundary in the source, so it has to be
    // combined form the bits, commming form two consecutive bytes
    // in the source
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < nob; ++i)
        {
            window[window.Length - nob + i] = (byte)((source[sbtci + i] << nfbbte)
                | (source[sbtci + 1 + i] >> (8 - nfbbte)));
        }
    }
    else// The bit substring coppied into one byte in the window
    // doesn't cross byte boundary in the source, so whole bytes
    // are simply coppied
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < nob; ++i)
        {
            window[window.Length - nob + i] = source[sbtci + i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array fits into an unsigned int:

```
int main () {
    unsigned int curnum;
    unsigned int num = 0x2492;
    unsigned int pattern = 0x1;
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int mask = 0;
    unsigned int n = 3;
    unsigned int count = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        mask |= 1 << i;
    }

    for (i = 8 * sizeof(num) - n; i >= 0; i--) {
        curnum = (num >> i) & mask;
        if (! (curnum ^ pattern)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your byte array and pattern each to a `std::vector<bool>`, then call `std::search(source.begin(), source.end(), pattern.begin(), pattern.end());`. Despite `vector<bool>`s idiosyncracies, this will work.

Comment: This will certainly be much less efficient than @PeterK’s proposed solution. `std::search` isn’t specialized for `vector<bool>::iterator`.

Comment: The second sentence is a strong statement, but generally true. However, I disagree entirely with the first. His is certainly O(N*M). I expect a std::search() implementation to be far more efficient, and move on on the first non-match. That means you check on average 2 bits per possible position, for an overall average complexity O(N).

Comment: how do you expect `std::search` to beat O(N*M)? That’s very unrealistic/infeasible in general. Peter’s implementation uses O(N) (strictly speaking for for M <= 8 bit) because he XORs the bits all at once instead of comparing them one by one, so you get *exactly one* (plus one for every byte border overflow) comparison for each position in the array while `std::search` will perform *multiple* comparisons.

Comment: (cont’d) Of course, a theoretical performance of O(N+M) is possible but only using advanced string searching algorithms which generalize very badly (in particular they depend heavily on the alphabet size) and it’s a safe bet that `std::search` does *not* implement them.

Comment: I expect std::search to have an _worst-case_ complexity of O(N*M) just like PeterK's solution. The _average_ case, though, is O(N). The reason is that in the worst case, it's the last (Mth) bit of the pattern that doesn't match, but on average it's the second.